# Android Memory Monitor

Tags: java, android, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have confused in android memory monitor. I want know that how much maximum memory allocate android to use for application. My one activity use about 20 MB memory and its showing 12 MB free. But when I use another Activity its use about 73 MB and still showing 9.81 MB free.

[image]

My question is `Android allow more memory during run time if its require ?` 
if yes then

```
how much maximum its provide before application crash ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory monitor doesn't show the maximum the app can use.  It shows the size of the currently allocated heap. The free number is the amount of that allocation still free.  If you need more memory than the allocated heap, it will allocate a larger heap, until the OS itself runs out of memory.  Then it will start killing other apps.  Then, if all else fails, it will throw an OutOfMemoryException and kill your app.